# Swift - Unwrapped string still displaying as Optional

Tags: swift, swift3

I've been using Swift for awhile, but i still struggle with understanding `optionals` on a daily basis.  It is the hardest thing for me to grasp currently.

I'm having trouble unwrapping this `UserDefaults` value to not include the `Optional()` surroundings.

**Storing the value**

```
globals.defaults.set(String(describing: cardView.backgroundColor), forKey: "bgColor")
print(String(describing: cardView.backgroundColor!))
//print this: UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1
```

**Reading the value**

```
let tValues = def.string(forKey: "bgColor")!.components(separatedBy: " ")
print(tValues)
//print this: Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace", "1", "1)
```

`def` is an instance of `UserDefaults.standard`.  As you can see i'm force unwrapping the key when i read it.  And i've tried doing it there and also at `print(tValues)!` instead.  But they produce the same result.

How do i get rid of the `Optional()`.

Comment: `backgroundColor` is an *optional* property, therefore `String(describing: cardView.backgroundColor)` gives the string "Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1)". You *don't* unwrap the color when saving it into the defaults.

Comment: When i print `String(describing: cardView.backgroundColor)` it is not optional.  See my comment in the _Storing the value_ section

Comment: In your *print* statement (second line) you unwrap the color. But not in the first line where you store the color into the defaults.

Comment: @MartinR That did it, thanks man.  I thought for sure i had tried that.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup http://stackoverflow.com/a/34366333/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, I found that extension shortly after fixing this issue and switched to using that extension.  It's very nice. I found it on a different SO question though.  Did you write it?  I did change the one function to match swift 3 convention ;) `func color(forKey: String)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275662/saving-uicolor-to-and-loading-from-nsuserdefaults/30576832#30576832

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I have just updated mine to Xcode 8.1 Swift 3.0.1

Comment: `let` statement made it optional. try `let obj:[String]` or use var

Comment: @AnkitThakur That's not what `let` means. I do know that.

Answer (score 0):

Optionals are there to protect us from the possibilities of a `nil` value in Swift. They could be tricky to wrap your head around and a pain to deal with at times but think of them as a shield from crashing your program. **NEVER** force unwrap. There is *usually* a better way.

Try safely unwrapping your UserDefaults object and then printing it. Something like this should work using an `if let` block.

`if let tValues = def.string(forKey: "bgColor"){
   //def.string(forKey: "bgColor") is now safely unwrapped
   print(tValues.components(separatedBy: " "))
}`